# What is the Minimal/Maximal number of nodes in quadratic tree?

Tags: data-structures

Lets consider that I have a quadratic tree (each node has 4 children).
Now, how can I compute the minimal and the maximal number of nodes in the tree when given that the height of the tree is ***d***?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? We love to help on this website, but we don't give away solutions without effort being shown

Answer (score 0):

Just as binary trees maximal number of nodes can be computed by using `2^d - 1`, quadratic trees can also by using `4^d - 1`. This is what would be considered a full tree.

This can be proven by the following: Let `n` be the number of nodes in a tree `t` of height `h`. 
Then, `h <= n <= 2^h - 1`.
`log4[n+1] <= h <= n`

For the minimum number of nodes, we need to know if the tree is expected to be full or not. If not, the minimum number of nodes for a tree of height `d` would simply be `d`.

It may be helpful to know if you are concerned with only internal or external nodes when determining the minimum number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

[binary tree diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Quc.png)

First if the height is d that means there are d+1 rows. But i think some conventions just see it as d rows.

second the maximal number of nodes is
 4^0 + 4^1 + 4^2 + ... + 4^d = (4^(d+1) - 1)/3

the minimum is easier each row has 1 node there are d+1 rows voala = d+1 nodes